# Add padding between collectionView cell and its border

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell

I want to add padding between collectionView cell and its border. Does anyone have any suggestion on doing that?

Comment: Subview within the cell so, the cell itself is the padding and you put your content in the subview

Comment: show your code or Xib

Comment: Exactly make use of A subview with Leading,Trailing,Bottom,Top with constraints to Margins or Make use of UIEdgeInsets

Answer (score 0):

Just give proper `Top, Leading, Trailing and Bottom` constraints of any view inside the cell. This will give you the effect of padding.